# Python Regex find / split exact word including parentheses at the end / excel formula

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

I am having difficulty with the last part of a regular expression, this is my attempt to split a string into

- capital letters not surrounded by parentheses
- double quotes surrounded characters (including the quotes)
- operators
- numbers
- the exact word `TODAY()`

```py
import re

s1 = 'A+" hello"+B'
s2 = 'A+(100-20)'
s3 = 'A-B+TODAY()-100'

print (re.split('([A-Z]+|["].?["]|[\=\+\-\%\*\^]|\bTODAY\(\)\b)', s1))
#expected ['', 'A', '', '+', '" hello"', '+', '', 'B', '']
#actual   ['', 'A', '', '+', '" hello"', '+', '', 'B', '']

print (re.split('([A-Z]+|["].?["]|[\=\+\-\%\*\^]|\bTODAY\(\)\b)', s2))
#expected ['', 'A', '', '+', '(', '100', '-', '20', ')']
#actual   ['', 'A', '', '+', '(100', '-', '20)']

print (re.split('([A-Z]+|["].?["]|[\=\+\-\%\*\^]|\bTODAY\(\)\b)', s3))
#expected ['', 'A', '', '-', '', 'B', '', '+', '', 'TODAY', '()', '-', '100']
#actual   ['', 'A', '', '-', '', 'B', '', '+', '', 'TODAY()', '-', '100']
```

edit: correction, meant to say double quote surrounded characters of any length

Comment: I don't think you're escaping the back slashes correctly. Try turning your pattern into a raw string: `r'([A-Z]+|["].?["]|[\=\+\-\%\*\^]|\bTODAY\(\)\b)','A-B+TODAY()'`

Comment: You might want to also include sample data which covers all edge cases (I'm not sure the parentheses edge case is being correctly shown here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern for matching TODAY() should be first alternative

```
import re    
print (re.split('(TODAY\(\)|[A-Z]+|["].?["]|[\=\+\-\%\*\^])','A-B+TODAY()'))
```